# C#.net System.Net.WebClient .. Server Side or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-side, scrape

I have a C#.net webform that does a simple response.write in content type JSON format.  It works greats from every client I test it with - including a TinyWebDB API call from an Android phone.. but don't worry about that API for this question.

I added some serverside code to that web form to read and scrape a web page as follows.

```
System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
Stream myStream = myWebClient.OpenRead(what);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myStream);
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I'm under the impression that code is all Server Side!?

I tested the page from IE, FF and Chrome.. all work great. However If I attempt to call the web form page from TinyWebDB the call works great and I get data back, but  I get a 404 error on the server side read of the webpage??

It's almost as if System.Net.WebClient requires something from or is doing something on client itself.  i thought the reading of the page was all happening serverside and behind the scenes on my serer.  Why would my serverside code care about what browser or API initiated the call to the webform?

Should I be using another class?

Many Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible for it to be 'doing something' on the client: the code is on the server.  You're mistaken and the problem is something else

Comment: More information is necessary. Is there something, perhaps a query string variable or a web method, that determines if this code is called or not? Since it runs on the server-side, only implementation details like those could cause different behavior if the server is the same but the client differs.

Comment: I too would think so. I isolated everything and wrapped the above code in try/catch returning it's results to the API. From all clients I see output from  the page read the tinyWebDB API call.. that one gets information back saying The remote server returned an error:(404) Not Found. I'm also seeing what it tried to process and it matches all other clients.

Comment: here's what's really weird. the solution works when I call some pages, but I get a 404 if I try to call yahoo or google home pages ???

Answer (score 0):

That is serverside code.

Where does the variable "what" get set? Is the form TinyWebDB client munging your form input values?

Is it possible that the site you are requesting is rejecting your request because you're hitting it too fast and you've just been unlucky with it being that client every time?

Comment: that is the only plausable thing I've been thinking too. I added a Sleep 3000 to the end of the block, but same result. It's not really a form, it's just doing a Response.Write in content type JSON. the code works great, it's just when I call from that API I get a 404 returned in the data.

Comment: I can see the API taking the full 3 seconds to come back and then the  404 is reported along with other fixed data my page is sending so I can see clearly that the above code is failing to connect, but only from my API call. Same exact page tested from browsers returns good findings. Mind boggling.

Comment: This is ODD, but via my API TinyWebDB, I'm sending a query string that I attempt to scrape with webclient as mentioned. When I look at the query string text it looks fine, but when I perform a Length on it - it reports some 10 characters more than what I see.  Is there a good function to remove all non ascii characters?

Comment: I suspect the problem is an encoding problem with http call. I'm seeing some 7 or 8 extra characters, but all attempt to identify and remove them have failed. The TinyWebDb HTTP is likely expecting a JSON response which I am in fact doing, but on the way up it must be sending something foriegn to my page in the query string. Not sure how to clean this up.